# EntityFramework pence to pounds

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm building a WPF application. I made my database using Code-First.

I need to insert prices of items in pence (e.g. 500), but when prices will be displayed they should be in pounds (5,00).

I tried to do the "conversion" in the setter of my property

```
public decimal Price
{
   get { return price; }
   set { price = value/100 ;}
}
```

But, for some reason, when I drop manually the database, the values in my `ListView` are shown some times like 0,05 and other times like 500,00. Something must be wrong with this method.

How can I tell my database to consider last 2 numbers of my value as decimal?

Comment: You should not be doing such conversions in your Model. The correct place for such things is your ViewModel.

Comment: @IvanStoev Could you please explain? I'm a beginner

Comment: It's too big to be explained here. Search for MVVM pattern (heavily used in WPF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try something like this

```
public class YourClassName {
   public decimal Price { get; set; }

   [NotMapped]
   public decimal Pounds => Price/100;
}
```

Comment: it's equivalent to if (Pence == 0) Pounds = 0 else Pounds = Pence/100;

Comment: But price is a property of my class Item. You are doing a separate class for price

Comment: [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) explains how the ? operator is used. But not needed in this case, sorry, my bad. Usualy that's a workaround to avoid dividing by zero.

Comment: Just add the Pounds property to your class, it will work. I'll edit the answer

Comment: @GregoryHouseMD my prices are show as £ 500,00 , so it's not working

Comment: Are you using the Pounds property for displaying? The Pounds property has to be in the same class as the Price property

Answer (score 0):

In Entity Framework, the value returned by the "getter" is what will be stored to the database.  Therefore, anything you set on this property is going to be value/100.

What you want to do is establish a standard way you want to store the currency.  Probably in this case, "Pence" is best, and I'd re-word the property to make it self documenting (and remove the division).

```
public decimal PriceInPence
{
   get { return price; }
   set { price = value;}
}
```

Then I'd supply a method for getting the Pounds:

```
public decimal GetPriceInPounds()
{
   return price == 0m ? 0m : price/100m;
}
```

If you're using the MVVM pattern as hinted to by one of your question comments, you'd populate the view model with calls to GetPriceInPounds().