# c# convert pence in integer to pounds

Tags: c#

I need to store prices for items in a database. I need them in int and in pence (e.g. 100) but they have to be shown as pounds (1,00).

I tried dividing my price value by `/100m` like this:

```
private int price;
public int Price
{
  get { return price/100m; }
  set { price = value; }
}
```

But I have a convertion error (can't convert from decimal to int).

I must use int, since I need to avoid fractions of pence.

Comment: Integers by definition much be a whole number. No decimal points.

Comment: Yes, I know that int can't be devided, but I saw example using `m` with integer and they were working. Why here is not?

Comment: Are you sure you want to return an int? If you're successful with what you are trying to do you will truncate (remove) the pence.

Comment: `m` is a suffix for decimal

Comment: Do you have any examples of the input and output you are expecting? This sounds like a weird case since if you just remove the fraction part you loose data? Also, a property is generally "Get what you set", if a developer uses your `Price = 100` and then tries to view it using `var whatever = Price` it's expected to be the same value that you enter.

Comment: where do you need to show them as 1,00, in the database table or on the UI?

Comment: @AmmarHamidou in the implemented wpf.

Comment: You can't have a single property (`Price`) that has an `int` value when setting and a `money` value when getting. You'll need to pick one or the other. You might want to override `ToString` to provide a formatted value in pounds or add another method to return the value in non-pence units.

Answer (score 5):

To perform integer division, both operands must be of the integer type. So, remove the decimal suffix `m` in `100m`:

```
private int price;
public int Price
{
    get { return price / 100; }
    set { price = value; }
}
```

**Update** - So down below in a comment all of a sudden, you say you want a string format. Here it is btw:

```
string formattedPounds = String.Format("£ {0:0.00}", Price);
```

Comment: An int divided by 100 will result as 0 in any case

Comment: But if the `Price` property is supposed to return a number in Pounds, then int is the entirely wrong data type, because a perfectly valid number of pence that isn't a multiple of 100 isn't going to equate to an integer number of pounds.

Comment: Won't you lose precision with integer division here? He asked for pounds down to hundreds ("1,00").

Comment: But the OP says, he must use integer.

Comment: If you must use integer, why not format the result when you display it? Your application isn't going to care if it's formatted or not, that's something you deal with when presenting it to the end users.

Comment: @Jdsfighter maybe it is the best solution

Comment: Do you really need to use `int` for the price in pounds? As long as you use the int for the price in pence, you'll always avoid having a fraction of a pence, no matter what type you use for the price in pounds...

Comment: @HenrikIlgen I need to use int just for pence, you are right. I tried to do something like `public decimal Pounds => Price / 100;` , but I get 0..

Comment: @Koosshh56: `public decimal Pounds => Price / 100m;`, otherwise it'll perform integer division (as both `Price` and `100` are integers). Making one of them a `decimal` will fix your problem.

Comment: @HenrikIlgen If I do like you say, I will get £ 0,01

Comment: @Koosshh56: If your `Price` is `1`, that's what I would expect, yes... So, which value did you store in `Price`?

Comment: @HenrikIlgen I stored 100

Comment: Having a property setter and getter with different value semantics is just terrible. OP already had a (basically the same) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005590/entityframework-pence-to-pounds) and accepted the correct answer. This question should not have been answered at all, and definitely not this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont want integer division. just change the way you want to show this int.

```
private int price;
private NumberFormatInfo info = new NumberFormatInfo
{
    NumberDecimalSeparator = ","
};

public int Price
{
  get { return price; }
  set { price = value; }
}

public string GetPrice
{
    get
    {
        return (Price / 100d).ToString("##.00", info);
    }
}
```

Use `GetPrice` property instead to get the value you want.

Comment: don't know if using a string format would be ok. I have to insert my values inside a database, which column type is number.

Comment: @Koosshh56 If you are putting them into a DB then formatting shouldn't matter.  You are either inserting pences into an int column, or pounds into a decimal column, unless you want to truncate the value for some odd reason.

Comment: @juharr could you explain me better please?

Comment: @Koosshh56 you just need to store integer normally but show it in different way. `int` does not hold any information except 4 bytes for its integer value. btw the closer type to what you need would be double or decimal.

Comment: @Koosshh56 You're DB doesn't care about formatting.  All you need to decide is what type the column is and weather you want to put pence or pounds into that column.  Displaying the value with a decimal is formatting that has nothing to do with storing the data.  It's best to either store the pence as an int or pounds as a decimal so you don't lose resolution.  If you store pounds as an int then you cannot store something like 155 pence exactly you'd have to either store 1 or 2 pounds.

Comment: @juharr how can I format in a way that the las two digits of my value are the "decimal part"?

Comment: @Koosshh56 Let me be very clear here.  Formatting is for displaying the values.  Are you worried about displaying the values or storing them?  If you store 100 in an int column then you have to pull that value out of the DB then use something like `string.Format({0:C}, value/100m)` to create a formatted string representation of the value of "1,00".

Answer (score 0):

```
private int priceInPence;
public decimal priceInPounds {
   get { return priceInPence / 100m; }
   set { priceInPence = (int)(value * 100); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert an amount from pence to pounds , cents to dollars or whatever then you need to cast the amount to be divided to decimal.

[Example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lpqot9)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        NameValueCollection nvcFormVariables = new NameValueCollection();
        nvcFormVariables.Add("Amount","1356");

        //string sAmount = "13.56";
        int amount = int.Parse(nvcFormVariables["Amount"]);     
        Console.WriteLine(amount);
        decimal amountPaid = amount / 100;      
        Console.WriteLine(amountPaid);

        decimal dAmount = decimal.Parse(nvcFormVariables["Amount"]);
        Console.WriteLine(dAmount);
        decimal dAmountPaid = dAmount / 100;        
        Console.WriteLine(dAmountPaid);

    }
}
```